# Grid doesn't expand unless parent element is ContentPage

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am adding a grid element (XFGrid infagistics) to RootLayout

```
    <ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        ...
    </ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid x:Name="RootLayout">             
    </Grid>
    </ContentPage>
```

This will work fine, however when I place the Grid inside the ContentPage.Content element nothing happens! What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does ContentPage have HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment properties ? I'm not %100 sure but in the style template you might find some content alignment properties.Try setting them to Stretch.

Comment: So close! Just had to do this 
   grid.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
   grid.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

Comment: My bad , thought it was a normal XAML question.Glad to see you find your answer.